# Single or multiple queries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table. I need to output the results from all three but group them by date and show a count of records per day.

The tables are:

```
business_actions
----------------
id
article_id
business_id
action


articles
----------------
id
user_id
item
date 
time

users
------------------
id
name
role
```

I am not sure if I should try and get this all into a single query of run a query where I will get distinct dates and total record counts and then run additional queries to retrieve additional information?..

I started with this but did not get too far.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(business_actions.id) AS cnt,
      business_actions.action,
      articles.user_id,
      articles.item,
      articles.date,
      articles.time,
      users.*
FROM business_actions
LEFT JOIN articles ON (business_actions.article_id = articles.id)
LEFT JOIN users ON (articles.user_id = users.id)
WHERE business_actions.business_id = ".$busID."
ORDER BY articles.time DESC
GROUP BY articles.date      
LIMIT 20
```

Limit actually should be the number of days, and not records...

The final result should look something like:

```
July 20, 2015 (2)
    Some item -- 10:00 am
        Name: John M
        Role: Admin
        Action: login

    Another Item -- 10:30 am
        Name: Jeff M
        Role: User
        Action: publish

July 18, 2015 (3)
    Some item -- 2:00 am
        Name: Bill M
        Role: User
        Action: print

    Another Item -- 10:30 am
        Name: Bob W
        Role: Manager
        Action: exit

    One more item -- 2:00 pm
        Name: William N
        Role: User
        Action: logout
```

---

UPDATE: Here's [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4817d/1) based on Barmar's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to limit by the number of days, you need to join with a subquery that gets those dates.

```
SELECT
      cnt,
      business_actions.action,
      articles.user_id,
      articles.item,
      DATE(articles.date) AS date,
      articles.time,
      users.*
FROM business_actions
JOIN articles ON business_actions.article_id = articles.id
JOIN (SELECT DATE(date) AS date, count(*) as cnt
      FROM articles
      GROUP BY DATE(date)
      ORDER BY DATE(date) DESC
      LIMIT 20) AS dates
    ON DATE(articles.date) = dates.date
LEFT JOIN users ON (articles.user_id = users.id)
WHERE business_actions.business_id = 42
ORDER BY articles.date DESC, articles.time DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4817d/7)

Comment: Wow, this is very cool, however I am getting limited results returned. I've tried it in the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4817d/1 I also fixed my typo: articles.res_id should be articles.id

Comment: Needed to do the counting in the subquery, too. And in the fiddle, you have times in your `date` column, so I have to use `DATE(date)` to combine them all by date.